# What do I have access to when I connect to Work VPN

Tags: macos, vpn

Work has sent us VPN info of the company to work from home on snow days. In my previous work place we did have VPN but we also had work laptops so all the software that I needed for work was already installed. But here we have desktops and at home I have Mac and a Windows on Parallels desktop.
So my question is when I go home and connect to work VPN then what happens? I don't have any of the software installed on home machine. So when I am on VPN there is way to also remote desktop from my Mac to my Windows machine at work?

Comment: Your Office IT staff would be able to answer your question about remotely logging into your office computer.  We have no idea if thats possible thats entirely dependent on your IT department's configuration

Comment: VPN is network protocol used for connecting to a local network (LAN) from outside the network's infrastructure over a connected but untrusted third-party-network (in oyur case the internet) in a secure, encrypted way. It can be used for almost anything that uses that sort of tunnel. But most likely, you just get access to network internal resources that way - unless you are working with slim clients and all software is server based. But maybe you also have access to some remote-desktop tools - but how are we supposed to know?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because asking about the internal operations of a specific network.

Comment: What you can access completely depends on the network you are connecting to.  There is no way for us to know, or give any useful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to remote desktop to your work machine that is on the LAN at work.  The VPN connection will simulate your MAC (home PC) sitting on the desk next to your work PC.  You should also have network access to file shares and other servers/workstations.  All the above requires your IT staff has done some work and is allowing RDP through the VPN.  This would make sense as it would allow you to work from home as you are describing.  Drop a chat/call to your IT staff and get the details on RDP from the VPN.

Comment: `"you should be able to remote desktop to your work machine"` - This is making a lot of assumptions.

Comment: His work has desktops, he has VPN software from work.  Yes I am assuming RDP is and or can be enabled.  Pretty safe assumption with the information given.